# Disallow plugin activation on multi-site

Tags: wordpress

My plugin currently does not support multi-site wordpress. How can I gracefully disallow my plugin being activated on a multi-site website? When I say gracefully I mean, I want the user to try to click activate and receive a message such as 'This plugin does not support Mult-Site WordPress. Plugin cannot be activated.'.

Or can I remove the activate option on the Installed Plugins page? Whats the convention here?

Answer (score 0):

I found this page which can be very handy for you:
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/

You can use the register_activation_hook( **FILE**, 'pluginprefix_function_to_run' );
hook to check if the current site is a wpmu if it is you can then trigger a fnction to deactivate your plugin.

```
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'check_wpmu' );

function check_wpmu() {
if( is_multisite() ){
     add_action('update_option_active_plugins', 'deactivate_my_plugin');
   }
}

function deactivate_my_plugin(){
   deactivate_plugins('your_plugin_folder/your_plugin_file.php');
}
```

check_wpmu: is the function that WP will trigger when your plugin is first activated.
deactivate_my_plugin: is the function that will be triggered by check_wpmu if the wp is multisite and it will reactivate your plugin immediately.

Thanks,